# Transparent navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have found many answers here how to set the bar color of the `navigation controller` .

But i would like to set the navigation controller **background** to be transparent.

When i am setting the navigation controller's root view background color with :

```
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
 self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
```

I can see black color and i am not see the view that under this navigator, because the navigator itself has probably some color that i couldn't find how to change , and so it doesn't matter that the root view has alpha, because the navigator has some background color .
How would i set it to be clear color ?

Comment: Have you set the background colour of the window? - I think that defaults to black.

Comment: how would i do that ?

Comment: In the application delegate you will probably have a `self.window` try `[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]`

Comment: hide the navigationcontroller and place image with alpha 50%

Comment: tried that, not working... thats because the window is the root and i don't see it anyway because its under all views.

Comment: @Curnelious The view that you add to the navigation controller will also have a background colour. Since iOS7 setting the background on the view controllers to transparent in order to see the navigation background will cause it to look funny when pushing a new controller. Because of this I now set the background colour of each view.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge its not clear what you say. have you read my question? i showed there that i DO set the background color of the first view in the navigation controller ....

Comment: @FahimParkar you can't hide navigation controller (or you can show me how?)

Comment: Apologies I read it as this `[self.navigationController.view setBackgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought you already were - Hence all the comments.

To set the background colour of the navigationControllers view do the following

```
[self.navigationController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
```

Sorry for the confusion.

W